# Map of Sets in google collection

Tags: java, guava

I am struggeling a little bit in fiding the proper googles [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implementation of
something like this :

```
Map<T,Set<K>>
```

it would be even cooler to find a TreeSet implementation.

```
Map<T,TreeSet<K>>
```

I am been searching for a half an hour around and didnt find it , the only thing I found that was TreeMultiMap [implementation](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) , but it is really confusing and its implementation is very differnt.

Edited :

Nevermind , actually the Map I found was the right one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's [HashMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html), which is analogous to a `HashMap<K, HashSet<V>>` and [TreeMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html), which is analogous to a `TreeMap<K, TreeSet<V>>`. What did you find confusing?

By the way, the google-collections library is unmaintained and shouldn't be used anymore. Use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), which replaced google-collections, instead.